# Is pd.get_dummies the same as simply including categorical variable in statsmodel ols?

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, dummy-variable, panel-data

I have panel data from an experiment that looks like this:

| account | usage | yearmonth | pre/post | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 121 | oct 2019 | pre | control |
| 1 | 124 | Nov 2019 | post | control |
| 2 | 120 | oct 2019 | pre | treatment |
| 2 | 118 | nov 2019 | post | treatment |

In my data I have about 50 months and a lot more accounts.

I'm using the statsmodel formula/patsy to run an ols to evaluate the results.

This isn't the exact model specification I'm using but for the sake of the question:

```
smf.ols("usage ~ C(group, Treatment('control'))* C(pre/post, Treatment(pre)) + yearmonth), df).fit()
```

My question is, when I include the 'yearmonth' variable in my formula, does statsmodel treat it as a dummy variable or do I need to use pd.get_dummies on it first then use this model:

```
 smf.ols("usage ~ C(group, Treatment('control'))* C(pre/post, Treatment(pre)) + oct 2019 + nov 2019), df).fit()
```

If I was to use the latter, my formula is going to be super long. So do I need to do it that way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the default categorical encoding is `Treatment` if the column is a text column.  In this case `Treatement` returns `K-1` categories, such that one of your `yearmonth` values will be considered the baseline, and you will see coefficients for all of the other dates except that one.  You can see this in detail [here.](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/contrasts.html#treatment-dummy-coding)

`pd.get_dummies` by default does not act this way.  It will created columns for every categorical value, meaning you will have one additional column using this method.

If you wished to use `pd.get_dummies`  you would need to set `drop_first=True` paramaeter.  You can find the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

In short there's nothing wrong  w/the first approach as it is in fact getting dummies behind the scenes, it's just worth noting it's `K-1`, not `K` categories.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. That makes total sense. I guess my follow up question would be, is there a way I can get the K categories without having to type out every single column generated by pd.get_dummies?

Comment: They will print out in the summary

Comment: Sorry Chris, I wasn't very clear with my question. My issue is, once I have used pd.get_dummies, it generates about 40 new columns in my df. If I want to include those 40 columns into my statsmodel formula, I would have to spend a lot of time typing out each column header (months). Is there a faster way of including all these months generated by pd.get_dummies into the statsmodel formula?

Answer (score 0):

get_dummies create a column for every categorical value.  you concatenate the results into your dataframe and drop the category column.   get_dummies allows for categorical rank. whereas df['category'].astype(category) does not.  you can use labelEncoder to set categories that are unique and don't require ranking like male and female.